# How can I get the .CRX file of a downloaded chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way for me to get the Crx file of a downloaded extension? I found the folder that has the extensions, I just don't know which one it is. Thanks

Comment: Chrome doesn't store the CRX file. It unpacks the installed extensions. You can download it as CRX from the web store by installing and using [CRXViewer extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-extension-source-v/jifpbeccnghkjeaalbbjmodiffmgedin) on an open page in the web store of the extension you want to download: click CRXviewer icon, click "view source", click "CRX".

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the crx plugin file, and if so, you can download the chrome plugin here: https://chrome-extension-downloader.com/

Comment: Extensions aren't plugins. These are completely different technology stacks in Chrome.